# How to insert key value pair inside an array in mongo db using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, nosql

When i Try to push key:value pair with the following code, it inserts data as object instead of key value pair. Following is the code im using to insert data into MongoDb

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("Test");
    var myquery = { userId: "test@gmail.com" };
    // var newvalues = { $set: { name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123" } };
    var newvalues = {
        $push: { questionAnsId: { $each: [{ wk: 5 }] } }
    }
    dbo.collection("Forms").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document updated");
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Upon inserting data, this is what im getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XWqa.png)

instead of saving data in
`questionAnsId: {Object}`
i want to save it as
`questionAnsId:{key:value, key:value}`

Any Idea how to solve this ?

Comment: `{key:value, key:value}` is an object, perhaps that is the only way that output can display the data (array of objects)

Comment: It is correct, as mongodb saves data that way only.